# Gas line pressure testing, is there an acceptable limit for losses?

Tags: gas, air-leaks, pressure

Last week I finished installing the gas home runs in a house I'm working on.  Never really done this before, but I figured I'd take a shot at it since it was only 20 ft of pipe.

Last Saturday, with all valves open except the main and the last valve before the appliance, I pressurized the line to 15PSIG.  When I left that night, still at 15.  Monday morning it was at 14.  Tuesday evening it was at 11.  Today it was down to 5.  Obviously, I don't want gas issues, but nothing is going to stay pressurized forever without maintenance.  Is there a rule of thumb, practical limit?

Comment: Best rule of thumb: **any leak will only get worse** so fix it.

Answer (score 6):

### You have a leak, and given that it's gas piping, you need to fix it.

For an air compressor, you might live with that sort of leak, but you don't have to.

***For gas, it's unacceptable.***

"Nothing is going to stay pressurized forever without maintenance" - for adequate values of forever, sure, the pipe will rust away. My "properly assembled" portable air tank, with a gauge and a quick-disconnect and a hose left on the quick disconnect with another quick-disconnect and a tire chuck holds pressure for (at least) months. If your gas piping won't hold pressure for a week, that's going to be a problem.

Small variations (which can go up as well as down) may be seen due to changes in temperature. I very much doubt that's the case for your pipe. Add more pressure, get out the soapy water (plus glycerine if you can find some, or buy "leak detector fluid" if you like - or just bubble solution for blowing bubbles) and start checking every joint. At least one is bubbling and needs to be remade properly.